# How to make accordion panel open if it has anchor link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an accordion. I have such that if there is an anchor inside the accordion, then if there is a link with the anchor the concerned accordion panel will open.

What I am basically asking is this.

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });
  </script>


<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3><a name="myAnchor"></a>
  <div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
    purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
    velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
    suscipit faucibus urna.
    </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: if you click on the inside anchor what should happen - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/whhbv61x/1/

Comment: Are you stating that if you click a link, and the anchor is inside an accordion section,. how to progrmaticaly open the accordion section?

Comment: Let us say we have an anchor "myanchor" that lies inside an accordion panel. And the panel is closed by default. Somwehere else there is a link mywebsite.com#myanchor. I expect the accordion panel to open up when someone visits mywebsite.com#myanchor . The anchor is just a link anchor inside the content. In my case, that does not happen

Comment: Don't use the index, just use the parent() function to find the one to open. If I understand you correctly. If you mean that inside lets say section panel 2, an anchor is to open section panel 1, then you can just find the anchor, then do anchor.closest(".trigger:).trigger("click"); If I understood your question. Using closest() goes up the DOm so will find the accordian panel the anchor is related to, then you manually trigger the click event on it, opening that panel of the accordian.

Comment: If this is what you are expecting, I can write a snippet.

Comment: Not exactly. I can have a link like mywebsite.com#myanchor in another portion of the website , not necessarily on the particular accordion. The anchor "myanchor" stays inside the accordion panel (maybe 2). Clicking on the link will open the particular panel. The anchor stays as part of the content inside the panel.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to open based on url the href of that anchor needs to have the same hash in it if that is what you want to use.

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
var hashName = hash && hash.replace('#','');
$('.accordionModule .accordionPanel .content a').filter(function(){
    return this.hash === hash;
    // or
     return this.name === hashName;       
}).closest('.accordionPanel').find('.trigger').click();
```

OR

```
$('.accordionModule .accordionPanel .content a[href$=' + hash +']')
  .closest('.accordionPanel').find('.trigger').click();
```

So url = `mywebsite.com#myanchor` would match `<a href="#myanchor"></a>`

Comment: I like this example. Nice method.

Comment: Looks nice.. However user is adding name attribute rather than the href for the anchor.. Is possible? as in <a name="myanchor"></a>

Comment: sure...use whatever you want

Comment: $('.accordionModule .accordionPanel .content a[href$=' + hash +']').closest('.accordionPanel').find('.trigger').click();   will only look for a link with href having the hash. Am I correct? However how to look for a href with name = hash

Comment: a[name :D works. I think I need sleep. I had only 10 hours of sleep in last 2/3 days. Sorry for such small stuffs

Comment: added `name` to filter approach in question

Comment: Same here lol. I too need to sleep more, but to be a great father, husband, developer, and contributor, sleep is not acceptable..  lol  I do like @charlietfl example better though. Always cool to see what people come up with in a hurry, and how they all view a problem/solution differently. Man I love coding!

Answer (score 1):

Example, if I understand yo correctly on wanted functionality:

```
var userUrl = window.location.href.split( '#' )[1];
$('.accordionModule .accordionPanel .content a').each(function( index ) {
    if ($( this ).attr('name') == userUrl ) {
        var $theTarget = $("a[href='" + userUrl + "']"); //gets the anchor targeted
        //then open the corresponding panel
        $theTarget.closest('.accordionPanel').find('.trigger').click();
    }
});
```

I hope this is what you are asking. It is late, and Im getting tired.  lol